# An error occurred while creating project - Eclipse

Tags: java, php, mysql, eclipse, wordpress

I am trying to to setup Xdebug with Eclipse for the purpose of looking at how Wordpress works by stepping through code.  I have successfully installed

- XAMP 2.5 (Apache and MySql)
- Wordpress 3.7.1 locally.
- Xdebug 2.1.1
- Eclipse Version: Kepler Service Release 1, Build id: 20130919-0819 (64 Bit)
- JRE 7 (64 Bit)
- PDT (PHP Development Tools)

When I do `File -> New -> PHP Project` I get

```
Problems encountered while setting project description.
Error configuring nature 'org.eclipse.php.core.PHPNature'.
org.eclipse.dltk.core.IBuildpathEntry.isContainerEntry()Z
```

What does this mean?  How do I fix it?

Comment: look at this tutorial http://docs.joomla.org/Configuring_Eclipse_and_Xdebug

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and fix it right now. I think the reason is that some components are not compatible with others. Try to download PDT again: http://download.eclipse.org/tools/pdt/updates/3.3. If eclipse shows PDT is installed, delete it first from Help->About Eclipse->Installation information->Find PDT and uninstall.